# Extracting UUID string from a text using shell script commands

Tags: shell, parsing, text, uuid, cut

I have a text line as:

```
host_id -------------------------------------- f5f4d3e7-fdc4-49f2-b32c-13280bc7db66 (1 rows)
```

And I want to extract only the UUID value within the text using shell script as I need to run this on ubuntu to execute some other commands using the value. I tried using `cut` command:

```
cut -d '-' -f2 | cut -d '(' -f1
```

But couldn't succeed to specify the `cut` character for before and after of the UUID string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem using `cut -d'-'` in your case is that the field (`-f`) values you will have to add is not 2 but 38 and above (that's the number of consecutive `-` symbols in your string), because of how `cut` works. This is the output you will get if you just set the field 39 (using `cut -d'-' -f39`):

```
f5f4d3e7
```

But also the UUID string you want contains additional hyphens, so if you still want to get it that way (using `cut`) you will have to expand your field selection, in this case by adding `-f39-43`. But that just will not solve the problem of showing the string "(1 rows)" after it, so by running `cut -d'-' -f39-43` you will get this:

```
f5f4d3e7-fdc4-49f2-b32c-13280bc7db66 (1 rows)
```

And that's why you used a second `cut` filter to just pick the UUID value string. While this is okay, it seems to be pretty much handy using `awk`, which will solve all these problems in one single command:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Or if your string is not coming from a file:

```
echo "host_id -------------------------------------- f5f4d3e7-fdc4-49f2-b32c-13280bc7db66 (1 rows)" | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Comment: thanks @hads0m !  String | awk '{ print $3 }' works perfect for my case. I should have noticed the space between ----- and f5f4... Also, thanks for explaining how cut -d works.